# How to use a globally local gradle installation instead of downloading a zipped wrapper everytime?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

I have installed gradle, and I create a new react-native project, when I execute react-native run-android(or run-ios), it will download a new copy of graddle-2.10.zip, how can I config the system or the project to use my local global gradle installation, other than to download from the internet, wasting more time and more storage?

Comment: There should be an Android Studio setting to use a locally installed Gradle binary. It should say (recommended) next to the wrapper option, though

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using Gradle wrapper to build your project (`./gradlew`).

However, I don't see how it is a big problem for you: downloaded Gradle distributions are cached in user home and each version is downloaded only once. So after you build your project for the first time, each following build will reuse already downloaded Gradle distribution.

But if you really want to use the Gradle distribution that you downloaded and installed yourself (which I only needed once when configuring gradle build on a Jenkins server without access to Internet), then you can build the project using explicit path to that Gradle distribution: `/path/to/gradle/distribution/bin/gradle`. For convenience you can add `/path/to/gradle/distribution/bin` to `PATH` environment variable and just call it as `gradle`.

Comment: Thank you very much ,I know it's recommended to use gradle wrapper, but it's really annoying to take a long time on downloading different versions of gradle. So I downloaded them(maybe not all versions) through Chrome,and set the Environment path `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to the folder where the downloaded files(mentioned above) were ,then modify gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties,set `distributionUrl=file\:/path/to/downloaded/gradle-2.xx.xx-all.zip`,after that it just moved on compling instead of blocked on downloading.

Answer (score 1):

As it mentioned here [Building React Native from source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html#additional-notes)

```
gradle.projectsLoaded {
    rootProject.allprojects {
        buildDir = "/path/to/build/directory/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    }
}
```